# two switch forward inverted transformer

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

How does it happen if I use an inverted transformer in a two switch forward converter?
please consider practical conditions.

regards.
ras

[image: two switch forward inverted transformer]

Comment: Your question ist fairly unspecific. Could you try to narrow your Problem, please? As it stands, it looks like you're trying to find a textbook explanation about SMPS design / 2SF converters, which is not a very good fit for this site.

Comment: i have made two switch forward converter but incorrectly the secondary transformer has been wounded inversely! ( as the schematic shows ). so does the circuit work?

Answer (score 1):

with it set-up like that the transformer is being used as a coupled inductor, as the flux decays the output diode is forward biased and conducts, so you essentially have a flyback that's limited to the supply voltage instead of a forward converter.